# How to type a typescript function that has a Mixin as the param type?

Tags: typescript, mixins

Say I have:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function Tagged<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {
        _tag: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._tag = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have a function that takes instances of the class created by Tagged as a param. For example:

```
function printTag(taggedObj: Tagged(Person)) {
       console.log(taggedObj._tag);
}
```

How do I type this appropriately, right now this gives me a compilation error? Do I need to create another class? Like:

`class TaggedPoint extends Tagged(Person) {}`

A followup question then is, if I create

```
function printTag(taggedObj: TaggedPoint) {
       console.log(taggedObj._tag);
}
```

And then elsewhere I have

```
class OtherTaggedPoint extends Tagged(Person) {
    constructor(tag) {
        super(‘some string’);
    }
}
printTag(new OtherTaggedPoint());
```

Will this cause a compilation error, because `TaggedPoint` is not the same as `OtherTaggedPoint`?

Answer (score 1):

First i would provide a named interface for what the mix-in provides:

```
interface Tagged
{
    _tag: string;
}
```

Then i simply change the function signature to that:

```
function printTag(taggedObj: Tagged)
{
    console.log(taggedObj._tag);
}
```

The compiler will recognize that a `Tagged(Person)` implements that interface.

If a function actually needs a `Tagged(Person)` i would use an intersection:

```
function printTaggedPerson(taggedPerson: Tagged & Person)
{
    console.log(taggedPerson.name); // Access to property of Person
    console.log(taggedPerson._tag); // Access to property of Tagged
}
```

---

Regarding the follow-up question: TypeScript uses structural typing, so if the classes are structurally the same, no error will be thrown.